# In C#, is it possible to pass objects that are supposed to be formatted by String's format method as an array?

Tags: c#, string, format

If I have a string, say, "[{0:000}*{1:00000}]" then it is possble to do some formatting like this in C#: String.Format("[{0:000}*{1:00000}]", 2, 3);

Let us assume that I have a list (or an array) of integers:

```
List<int> intList = new List<int>();
            intList.Add(2);
            intList.Add(3);
```

Is it somehow possible to pass that list to String's format method so that formattings will be carried out in the way that the ints' index corresponds to the format-string's index ({0:..., {1:..., that is)? I have strong doubts on the feasibility of this, but I would be very beholden to any inventive mind proving that it can actually be done.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: The solution is [F1]. Write `String.Format` and press [F1]. then navigate to the last overload https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/b1csw23d(v=vs.110).aspx. Ask the documentation, it knows everything.

Comment: Try following : string[] array = input.Split(new char[] { '[', '{', '}', ']' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToArray();

Comment: Actually you just need to replace the square brackets :             string format = input.Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "");
            string output = string.Format(format, 2, 3);

Answer (score 1):

string.Format accepts single objects or arrays of objects as parameters. Your argument has to match the method signature.

```
var result = string.Format("[{0:000}{1:00000}]", intList.Cast<object>().ToArray());
```

Passing your list as an array of objects does exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

From the method `String.Format(String, Object[])` [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d(v=vs.110).aspx):

This method will :

> Replaces the format item in a specified string with the string representation of a corresponding object in a specified array.

Like :

```
var foo = new List<int>{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
Console.WriteLine("{0}, {3}, {2}, {1}, {4}", foo.Cast<object>().ToArray());
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZLiNji

The indice will be those of the array but take care that:

> Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list